# Comparing date string in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have two dates I am comparing.

```
a = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-03-09','12:09 AM')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-03-09','11:56 PM')
a = 2019-03-09 12:09 
b = 2019-03-09 11:56 
if a > b:
    print('yes')
```

What's happening is a is greater than b.  But it shouldn't be. It seems like its cutting off the am and pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using that `strptime` function correctly, it should be like this:

```
a = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-03-09 12:09 AM','%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')
b = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-03-09 11:56 PM','%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')

if a > b:
    print('yes')
```

And then, you're overwriting `a` and `b` anyway.

Here is the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for how to use strptime

Comment: I just spotted my error.  Thanks I will upvote and accept your answer.